# Scrolling down a webpage using selenium chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to retrieve all relevant URLs from a site, however in order to render them all I have to scroll down the webpage, otherwise it returns 500 URLs.

I have two key functions.
One that gets all od the relevant URLs:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver 

def scrapeCategory(url):
    url1 = url + "?max=10000"
    html = getHtmlHeadless(url1)
    site = htmlParser(html)
    links = site.findAll('a', {'class':'itemImage', 'data-e2e':'product-listing'}, href=True)
    url_list = []
    for link in links:
        url_list.append("https://www.size.co.uk"+link['href'])
    return url_list
```

By specifying that max=10000 I ensure that all of the listings are on 1 page (rather than having to jump from page to page).

```
url1 = url + "?max=10000"
```

And a function that retrieves the HTML, employing a headless chromedriver:

```
def getHtmlHeadless(url):
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    # specify headless mode
    options.add_argument('headless')

    # specify the desired user agent
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver',options=options)

    # Ensure it is a string
    if ( type (url)!= str):
        print("The input must be a string or list of strings")
    driver.get(url)
#     driver.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    html = driver.page_source
    return html
```

Following advice given in other similar queries I have tried applying

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

and

```
driver.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

However it does not seem to be doing the job as I either get a maximum of 500 URLs, or in the latter case I get an error.

Error:

```
<AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'>
```

I am suspecting that I am not placing the

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

in the correct place. However I do not know where else to place it.

Comment: 1. To better understand issue with option1(with javascript executor), can you share the value of `url`? 2. In Option2, you are calling `send_keys` which is not a function of `WebDriver` but `WebElement`. 3. Does this website use lazy loading? If not, then you don't need to scroll to bottom of page to get the page source.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

> 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

`send_keys()` is a method on `WebElement` class, not `WebDriver`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. If someone's still looking for executing the scroll page through Selenium without send keys method.

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight*0.90);")

    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```